# Normalisation of Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, normalization

How do I normalize these tables: Owing to the fact that I cant create a foreign key on a partial part of a Composite Key. The **strong text** signify the primary keys in the database.

Product(**ItemCode**, ItemName, SellingPrice)

Supplier(**SupplierName**, Phone, Address)

SupplierProducts(**SupplierName**, **ItemCode** , SupplyPrice)

Comment: The tables here look fine to me. However, if you are trying to now reference `SupplierProducts` in a different table you might be well suited to give it it's own unique primary key.

Comment: mysql doesnt allow me to link either itemcode or suppliername to the SupplierTable. As you cant create a foreign key on just one part of the composite key. So how do I link the tables together

Comment: you might be well suited not to have Names as PK

Comment: the composite key is nice. nothing saying you can't have a key on one column in addition to it

Comment: Please provide your DDL for the tables and I can help you more.

Comment: @Drew . I guess not all internet sources are correct. You could actually create a foreign key on one part of a composite key. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside your choice of `Supplier.SupplierName` as a PK, the tables look like a perfect *normal*(ized) m to n relationship between the `Product` and the `Supplier` tables. 
Add a *unique* index on the pair of `SupplierProducts.SupplierName` and `SupplierProducts.ItemCode` and you're good to go

Answer (score 1):

```
create table Products
(   ItemCode int auto_increment primary key,
    ItemName varchar(100) not null,
    SellingPrice decimal(10,2) not null,
    updateDt datetime not null
    -- throw in some indexes
);

create table Suppliers
(   SupplierId int auto_increment primary key,
    SupplierName varchar(100) not null -- allows you to change a supplier name
    -- throw in some indexes once you add more columns
);

create table SupplierPhone
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    SupplierId int not null,
    PhoneNum varchar(20) not null,
    PhoneType int not null, -- have a FK somewhere
    -- FK back to Suppliers
    -- throw in some indexes
    key (SupplierId)
);

create table SupplierAddr
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    SupplierId int not null,
    Addr1 varchar(100) not null,
    Addr2 varchar(100) not null,
    -- etc all that jazz
    AddrType int not null,  -- have a PK somewhere
    -- FK back to Suppliers
    -- throw in some indexes
    key (SupplierId)
);

create table SupplierProducts
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    SupplierId int not null,
    ItemCode int not null,
    SupplyPrice decimal(10,2) not null,
    updateDt datetime not null,
    -- FK back to Suppliers
    -- FK back to Products
    -- throw in some indexes
    unique key (SupplierId,ItemCode) -- won't allow dupes on this combo
);
```